# Move div and set the color name on top

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how to rotate div and set the color of div .By default red is in top so it print red.But when user rotate clockwise or anticlock wise it print the name of color on top . I think I have to mouse over and mouse out event can you please help me making a demo . http://jsfiddle.net/cdZ73/1/

```
<label style="display:inline-block">color Name:</label>
<label>red</label>
<div id="full">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="pink"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>    
</div>
```

how to get touch start event so that they change position ? change label text ?

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/W62Qa/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "rotate". Assuming that what you want is changing the color of the boxes, I made some changes in your HTML and CSS, and then made the classes of the boxes change when clicked.

HTML:

```html
<label style="display:inline-block">color Name:</label>
<label class="colorName">red</label>
<div id="full">
    <div id="top" class="red"></div>
    <div id="left" class="pink"></div>
    <div id="bottom" class="blue"></div>
    <div id="right" class="green"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#full > div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
}
#top { top:10px; left:200px; }
#left { top:120px; left:20px; }
#bottom { top:220px; left:200px; }
#right { top:120px; left:350px; }

.red { background:red; }
.pink { background:pink; }
.blue { background:blue; }
.green { background:green; }
```

JavaScript:

```js
var arr = ["red","pink","blue","green"];

$('#full').on('click', 'div', function() {

    $('.colorName').text($(this).attr('class'));  

    var sel = arr.indexOf($(this).attr('class'));

    $(this).closest('#full').find('div')
        .first().removeClass().addClass(arr[sel])
        .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+1)%4])
        .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+2)%4])
        .next().removeClass().addClass(arr[(sel+3)%4]);
});
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/cdZ73/3/) to test it.

A few things to notice:

- I assigned an `id` for each square to be able to separate position and color in the CSS, so we can change the color of a square just by changing its class.
- In the javascript, the colors in the array are in the same order than in the classes of the squares (counter-clockwise in this case).
- When a square is clicked, we get the index of its color and use it to replace the class of each square with the new one.
- If you uncomment the alerts in the fiddle, it will show you the html of the squares before and after the class changes.

I know the code could be cleaner or better in some ways, that was just a quick try.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sir thanks for posting the answer .But you correct I need just shift left and right when user use swipe left and right gesture

Comment: Try using [the swipe event](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_swipe.asp), for example replacing the `.on('click', ...)` with `.on('swipeleft', ...)` or `.on('swiperight', ...)`.

Comment: Or just use a jquery plugin with swiping capabilities, I'm sure you can find quite a few of them just googling a bit.